# Como colocar o valor referente ao eixo y junto ao marcador do gráfico?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics, seaborn

Olá,
Gostaria de que junto aos pontos do gráfico aparecessem também os valores referentes ao eixos y.
Desde já agradeço!

```
plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))  
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)  
sns.lineplot(x = dados_corona.index, y = 'Confirmados', data = dados_corona, marker = 'o', color = 'black')  
sns.lineplot(x = dados_corona.index, y = 'Mortes', data = dados_corona, color = 'red', marker = 'o')  
plt.title('Dias de infecção X Casos confirmados / Mortes - COVID-19', color = 'red')  
plt.ylabel('Casos confirmados / Mortes', color = 'red')  
plt.xlabel('Dias de infecção', color = 'red')  
plt.yscale('log') #coloca o eixo y em escala logaritmica  
plt.show()
```

O resultado atual é o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez a resposta desta pergunta possa te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027653/adding-labels-in-x-y-scatter-plot-with-seaborn

Comment: Use `plt.text` 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método `ax.text` passando a ele a posição XY do texto e o texto a ser exibido, por exemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = range(10)
ys = [x**2 for x in xs]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # inicializa Figure e Axes
ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='o')
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):  # adiciona um texto para cada ponto XY
    ax.text(x-0.5, y+0.2, y)

plt.show()
```

Note que adicionei um pequeno "desvio" ao chamar `ax.text` para que o texto não fique em cima de cada ponto, dificultando a leitura. Você terá de testar alguns valores de desvio até encontrar um valor bom para seu gráfico, de acordo com os limites do seus eixos X e Y.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]